# Jersey multi-part configuration with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, multipart

I'm having problems while trying to parse a HttpServletRequest containing multi-part files. I have tried all the solutions to other posts regarding the exception I'm facing but nothing seems to work.

These are the relevant dependencies for the project:

```
<project>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

SpringBoot Application initializer:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ApplicationBoot.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationBoot.class, args);
    }
}
```

Jersey Initializer config and multipartResolver bean:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(AttachmentResource.class);
        register(ContentResource.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

}
```

And the class where I'm facing the problem regarding multi-part parsing and also the resource:

```
@Component
@Path("/attachments")
public class AttachmentResource {

    @POST 
    @Path("/store")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response store(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

        for (Part part : httpRequest.getParts()) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

When getParts() is called I receive 
***java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided***

I added these properties in application.properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=0
```

As found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

And also this is what SpringBoot is logging with debug output enabled on start up regarding Multipart config:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================

Positive matches:
-----------------
    MultipartAutoConfiguration matched:
        - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver', 'javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
        - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.http.multipart.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration#multipartConfigElement matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------
    MultipartAutoConfiguration#multipartResolver:
        Did not match:
            - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'multipartResolver' (OnBeanCondition)
```

Later edit:

If I deploy the application in a standalone tomcat 8 and add this in con/context.xml it works:

```
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
```

Or add a context.xml file under src/main/webapp/META-INF in the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="" allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"/>
```

But It doesn't work if I start the project with embedded Tomcat.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Did you find a solution for Spring Boot embedded tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how to use MultiPart with Jersey. If you want to get all the parts, you can use [`FormDataMultiPart`](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/apidocs/2.11/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html) as the entity parameter

```
@POST
public Response post(FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
    Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> parts = multiPart.getParts(); 
}
```

If you want get inject individual parts by name, you can use the `@FormDataParam` annotation, passing in the name of the part to the annotation.

```
@POST
public Response post(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
                     @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDatail) {

}
```

---

#### See also

- [Jersey docs for multipart support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)

Comment: Just edited my question. It works the way it is if it's deployed in a standalone tomcat 8 if I add allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"in context.xml. Don't know how to do this with embedded tomcat. I will also try out your suggestion. Thanks!